# External microphone recognize as headphone on Asus x450CA laptop

Tags: microphone

I use Ubuntu 16.04 on my Asus x450CA laptop. When i plug external microphone it's recognize as headphone. I did google and try to fix with hdajackretask and add `options snd-hda-intel model=,dell-headset-multi` to my alsa-base.conf. But it's still not good. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Asus x450CA has a *COMBO audio jack* designed for headphone+microphone similar to the ones you use with your smartphone.

It doesn't support standard microphones without an audio splitter:

[image]

Comment: Haha Who knew! +1 for pic.

Comment: Increasingly common in entry to medium level notebooks. It's cheaper (less parts, easier to design) and many customers prefer it so they can use the headphones/earphones bundled with (or bought for) their smartphones.

Comment: Thank you so much! I went to store to buy the audio spliter but they only have an usb soundcard. That's the right answer.